# How to sort just a specific part of an already sorted 2D Array depending on new values. But only if the first sorted values match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following problem:
I have an array with objects in it.
Every object has a score and a rank, like this:

```
    [
        { "score": 20, "rank": 12 }, 
        { "score": 20, "rank": 7 },
        { "score": 34, "rank": 4 }
    ]
```

First of all, I sort this descending by the score and store it into a 2-dimensional array.

```
    [34, 4]
    [20, 12]
    [20, 7]
```

But now, if there is the same score twice or more often I want those to be sorted by the rank. So whatever has the lowest rank will have a smaller index number. Resulting in:

```
    [34, 4]
    [20, 7]
    [20, 12]
```

I really don't know how to do this, I made some approaches, but they are a way to bad to mention them.

Comment: It will be nice to see how you do the first sort: _I sort this descending by the score and store in into a 2 dimensional array._. To see if we can improve the sort logic to approach your final goal.

Comment: `drivers.sort(sort2dArrDes);`
`function sort2dArrAsc(a, b) {
                if (a[0] === b[0]) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
                }
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the difference of `score` of two objects is `0` then return the difference of `rank` otherwise return difference of `score`

```js
const arr = [
    { "score": 20, "rank": 12 }, 
    { "score": 20, "rank": 7 },
    { "score": 34, "rank": 4 }
]

let res = [...arr]
             .sort((a,b) => (b.score - a.score) || (a.rank - b.rank))
             .map(x => [x.score,x.rank]);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not working correctly sorting. 
The output is: 
`
[
  [
    34,
    4
  ],
  [
    20,
    12
  ],
  [
    20,
    7
  ]
]`
but expected was:
`
[
  [
    34,
    4
  ],
  [
    20,
    7
  ],
  [
    20,
    12
  ]
]`

Answer (score 0):

Just use lodash and orderby 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could `sort` the array first and then just `map` over for the `Object.values`:

```js
const arr = [
    { "score": 20, "rank": 12 }, 
    { "score": 20, "rank": 7 },
    { "score": 34, "rank": 4 }
]

let result = arr.sort((a,b) => (b.score - a.score) || (a.rank - b.rank))
  .map(x => Object.values(x))

console.log(result)
```